# oracle - select all distinct IDs that are marked as 1 only if it includes the max date value for that ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where I am trying to find all of the ID's that have an associated confirmed=1 for its maximum date. The primary key is the ID & Date.

| ID | Date | Confirmed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 20210101 | 1 |
| Bob | 20210201 | 1 |
| Bob | 20210301 | 0 |
| Jim | 20210101 | 0 |
| Jim | 20210201 | 1 |

In this scenario, only Jim should be returned because the maximum date is 20210201 & is marked as 1. Bob is not returned because 20210301 is the maximum date is marked as 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `MAX` analytic function to find the latest date for each `ID` then filter for records that match the max date and are confirmed.

```sql
WITH
    sample_data (id, dt, confirmed)
    AS
        (SELECT 'Bob', '20210101', 1 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Bob', '20210201', 1 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Bob', '20210301', 0 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Jim', '20210101', 0 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Jim', '20210201', 1 FROM DUAL)
SELECT DISTINCT id
  FROM (SELECT d.id,
               d.dt,
               confirmed,
               MAX (d.dt) OVER (PARTITION BY d.id ORDER BY d.dt DESC)     AS max_dt
          FROM sample_data d)
 WHERE dt = max_dt AND confirmed = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Now say hypothetically my table had 100 columns. Would it now be necessary to indicate each column in the inner select ? or just the ones I am interested ?

Comment: you would only need to select the ones you are interested in

Answer (score 1):

You can use an analytic function such as `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
  FROM
  ( SELECT t.*, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id
                                   ORDER BY TO_DATE("date",'yyyymmdd') DESC ) AS rn
      FROM t ) 
 WHERE rn = 1
   AND confirmed = 1
```

sorting descendingly by "date" and grouping by "date" will yield the desired records with maximum date values for each primary key value

PS. "date" is assumed to be a string, and converted to date type

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4805958148b9aeda64090cff1f03b9b4)</kbd>

Comment: This query is missing selecting `confirmed` from the subquery. It is also returning Bob incorrectly when the latest "date" for Bob is not confirmed.

Comment: oh thanks I missed @EJEgyed

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Hey Thanks. I should have mentioned that the DATE was actually a VARCHAR2 datatype. In that case, is the TO_DATE() necessary ? Or can I simply just `ORDER BY date DESC` instead ?

Comment: Hi @user3696953 , you're welcome. Of course not necessary but a good habit to preserve a date column with a date data type. Btw, it implies that that column should be defined with date data type within the table. Moreover you can benefit the performance whenever indexed as a date column, and used within a query's where condition

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan And 1 last question. Why do you need the check of `rn = 1` ? When the row number equals 1 that is supposed to indicate something ?

Comment: As I already stated within the answer that we will be able to get the max value during the *sorting descendingly by "date"*  by making it equal to 1(the first value returning from the ROW_NUMBER() function) @user3696953